# Add text next to a word - Unix

Tags: shell, sed, aix

I would to search for a line and then add three lines next to it, i used sed but its giving me error,PFB the requirement

**Line to be searched** - Listen 29399

**Lines to be added**,

ServerName Server
SSLEnable

KeyFile /test/script/scripts

Script i used,

```
sed -i '/Listen 29399/a <VirtualHost Servername:29399>\n SSLEnable\n #SSLClientAuth none\n </VirtualHost>\n SSLServerCert ServerCert\n KeyFile KeyFile /test/script/scripts' httpd.conf
```

Error:

```
sed: illegal option -- i
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]
```

Please help.

AIX Server

**Update**

Please let me know how to replace a line with other three lines, like below
Source File:

```
Listen 29399
```

Result File content:

```
Listen 29499
<VirtualHost Sever:25344>
Key File=/test/script
```

Thanks in ton.

Comment: Your `sed` doesn't support `-i` (incline editing)

Comment: Then, can yuo please suggest me a way to do it?

Comment: Try without `-i`, i.e. `sed '/Listen 29399/a <VirtualHost Servername:29399>\n SSLEnable\n #SSLClientAuth none\n </VirtualHost>\n SSLServerCert ServerCert\n KeyFile KeyFile /test/script/scripts' httpd.conf`

Comment: Its giving error as sed '/Listen 29399/a <VirtualHost Servername:29399>\n SSLEnable\n #SSLClientAuth none\n </VirtualHost>\n SSLServerCert ServerCert\n KeyFile KeyFile /test/script/scripts' cannot be parsed   ...please help

Comment: Are you trying to append text or substitute? You should decide which one you want to do and remove the other part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Issues regarding the `-i` switch aside (your version of sed probably doesn't support it), [the standard syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/sed.html) to append lines using sed is this:

```
sed '/Listen 29399/a\
<VirtualHost Servername:29399>\
SSLEnable\
#SSLClientAuth none\
</VirtualHost>\
SSLServerCert ServerCert\
KeyFile KeyFile /test/script/scripts' httpd.conf
```

That's `a\`, followed by a newline, followed by the text to be appended. Some versions of sed allow you to specify the text to be appended on the same line, some don't - this is the portable way to do it. Also, `\n` isn't understood by all versions of sed - you can add a `\` to the end of each line to append a multi-line string as I have shown.

If that seems like a hassle to you, use awk instead:

```
awk '{print}/Listen 29399/{print "multi-line text\nto be inserted"}' file
```

Using either approach, to achieve an "in-place" edit, just redirect to a temporary file and then overwrite the original, i.e. `cmd orig > tmp && mv tmp orig`.

---

If instead of appending the text, it's a substitution that you want, then you can use sed like this:

```
sed 's~Listen 29399~Listen 29499\
<VirtualHost Sever:25344>\
Key File=/test/script~' file
```

I've used `~` to separate the parts of the `s` command to avoid needing to escape all of the `/`. Again, each line in the replacement ends with a `\`.

Alternatively, using awk:

```
awk '{sub(/Listen 29399/, "Listen 29499\n<VirtualHost Sever:25344>\n<VirtualHost Sever:25344>")}1' file
```

Effectively it's the same substitution, just using `\n` for newlines. The `1` at the end of the command means that every line of the input is printed.

Comment: You're welcome - I've edited again to show a method using sed that might work for you as well (but I personally prefer using awk with `\n`). Don't forget to accept my answer if your problem is solved by clicking on the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Vi is not the tool you normally want for editing files with scripts, but it is another way (first make sure the search will succeed with a grep and Listen is not the last line, as I said do not use it):

```
vi httpd.conf >/dev/null 2>&1 <<END
/Listen 29399
iVirtualHost Servername:29399
SSLEnable
#SSLClientAuth none
</VirtualHost>
SSLServerCert ServerCert
KeyFile KeyFile /test/script/scripts
**ESC**:wq!
END
```

**ESC** is the escape sequence for ESC, I add it in vi with `CTRL-V ESC`.